# Could I create a photorealistic 3D model of an object from photographs of the object taken from different angles?

Tags: graphics, 3d, photo, photos

Say I have a very large amount of photographs of an object, all from different angles, so that one can through these photographs view the object from whatever angle is desired.

Is there a way to take these photographs and combine them into a photorealistic 3D model of the object that could then be displayed just like a traditional 3D model and moved around/rotated?

The reason I am asking is that I am working on a project where a traditional 3D model will not do and we need photorealistic quality, but we would still like the ability to rotate, zoom and pan around the object.

Thanks for your help

Comment: yes you could, but it will require a lot of work. You can match photos to 3D models. However, I think you should try to find other solutions before you start on it.

Comment: I have a kind of answer in scope below, but It would be much cheaper to have a 3d artist render the object that to try to write a program that is capable of the same feat... but the program would be cooler.

Comment: I know that Lehrstuhl 8 at RWTH Aachen University is working on stuff like that, but i don't know if there is any Software available. http://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/index.php?id=55

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like [Photosynth](http://photosynth.net/). Check out the [demo at TED in 2007](http://www.ted.com/talks/blaise_aguera_y_arcas_demos_photosynth.html) for a nice example using images sourced from flickr to build a model of Notre Dame cathedral (about half way through the presentation).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little answer to your big big question...

- you will have to find the edges, interpret them as a boundary (like a series of different spline cross sections)
- interpolate enough missing points to give desired resolution, which could be done my using the parallel points in series a0,a1,a2... as a series of points in a bezier path. (like a string wound around the model)